# CorePlot real time Plot - Starting animation is very slow?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, core-plot

I am using CorePlot-Real time plot graph. Everything works great. My problem is that when the plotting starts, the plotting animation is very slow and it is not smooth. It looks like Jerk plotting. Is there any way to make that plotting very smooth? I am using CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved for real time plot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The graph has to redraw the plot and axes for each animation frame. Do everything you can to speed that up. The curved interpolation style requires a lot of computation, so make sure the plot doesn't have too many points offscreen. The curve fitting algorithm finds a curve through all of the data points, even ones not currently visible. Use simple line styles, no transparency, and no gradients. Remove tick marks and grid lines from the axes (set the corresponding line styles to `nil`) if possible.

Comment: Actually i am talking about the example of CorePlot real time plotting curve. I want to make that curve more smooth than curve given into the example. Is there any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the "Real Time Plot" demo, removing the tick marks and grid lines makes  a big difference. The axes have to be redrawn for each frame, so the less that needs to be drawn, the better. Are you testing on a device? Which one?

Comment: I'm testing on iPhone 5. and it still shows jerk at only starting screen and it shows smooth when screen starts scrolling.

Comment: The "Real Time Plot" demo adds plot points one at a time. It doesn't try to interpolate successive points to make the line grow smoothly until it extends across the screen. This would be fairly easy to do with the default linear interpolation between plot points. It would be more difficult to do it with a curved plot line.